# ExtJS 7.2 Change entire application "font-family" dynamically

Tags: extjs, extjs7

I am currently creating a project in ExtJS 7.2

How can I change the entire application `font-family` dynamically

Like allowing the user to select the best font by **example** from `drop-down list` and that has to be applied to the entire application.

I know that I can create the file `{project-folder}\classic\sass\var\all.scss` and just update the `font-family` inside it as the following

```
$font-family: 'Tahoma' !important;
```

but how can I change this value **dynamicly** ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Ext.util.CSS` to add css rules.

```
// as no * rule exists, you have to create a new stylesheet
Ext.util.CSS.createStyleSheet("* {font-family: 'Tahoma';}", "some-id")
```

Then you can update `*` rule with :

```
Ext.util.CSS.updateRule('*', "font-family", "Roboto");
```

Don't use `!important` here because of `font-ext`, `font-awesome` and `font-pictos` packages